# How to find the SNRb for the given error propabillity?

Tags: telecommunication

I am trying to solve this problem: 16-QAM system and want to find the SNRb in order the error propabillity to be Pb=10^-3, given the following(showed in the picture below) [useful functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b9rv.png)

I am trying to substitute P in Pb but i dont know how to continue because i can't find the Q function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.